# Scope array is not affected when bluring

Tags: angularjs

Having the following HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="phone in user.phones">
    <input type='text' value='{{phone}}' ng-model="phone" ng-blur="phoneBlur()"/>
</div>
```

and the following code:

```
$scope.phoneBlur = function() {
    const newPhones = $scope.user.phones.filter((item) => item != '');
    if(newPhones.length !== $scope.user.phones.length) {
        $scope.user.phones = newPhones;
    }
}
```

The if statement is never called. The idea is removing blank phones from the array and their inputs.

Comment: Seems like it does for me: https://jsbin.com/jiyusu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @MoshFeu I've just found the solution, it seems that the problem is that I cannot use the loop control variable as ng-model, otherwise it won't affect the array. The correct answer is `ng-model="user.phones[$index]"`. If you want place it as the an answer and I'll mark it as the right one.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You can answer your own question :)

Comment: @MoshFeu I know, but I don't think it is fair.

Comment: Sure it does. Anyway, you'll not get reputations for that, if it concern you..